# Why I need to set console to ttyS0, when booting linux on qemu-system-x86_64

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, qemu

I want to run linux on qemu to test some system design, I use default config for x86_64, I found that I must append "console=ttyS0" to boot arguments so that I can get kernel message, without the ttyS0 I can't get any output.

So I want to check qemu's device tree, another strange thing is that I found there is no device-tree directory under /sys/fireware.

I want to check following question:

1. why we need "console=ttyS0" to get output ?
2. doesn't x86 use device-tree during booting ?

Comment: 1) The kernel has to have means to out its log somewhere if you wish to follow at boot time (you always can read it via `dmesg`). QEMU on the other hand uses VFIO (virtual IO) communication protocol. You may choose whatever output for kernel console for which QEMU has a VFIO driver for, so what you said is not a strong requirement. **There is no need to specify `console=ttyS0`**.

Comment: 2) On x86 the ACPI is responsible for delivering device tree information (with only few exceptions). I think the _/sys/firmware/acpi_ should be present. **In 99.99% cases x86 does not require Device Tree (as part of OF specification) to be provided.**

Comment: All tutorials on the Internet use ttyS0, which makes me very puzzling, and if I replace it with tty0/hvc0 will not get any output

Comment: To have anything working in this scheme you have two have two things: VFIO driver, hardware driver in QEMU. Does QEMU have it?

Comment: What kind of devices are virtual consoles such as ttyx redirected to, and why I can only see them in the graphical interface of qemu, like Debian GNU/Linux 10 mindebian tty1 ?

Comment: Linux virtual consoles use a hardware PC's monitor and keyboard, so on an emulated system like QEMU they appear in QEMU's graphical interface, which is what is doing the graphics/keyboard emulation. ttyS0 is a serial port; on real hardware it goes out of an RS232 port on the back of the PC; in an emulated QEMU system it can be directed to various places, including the terminal you ran QEMU from.

Comment: Re tutorials, lots of setups can be made to work. The important thing is that all of (a) the command line options you give QEMU (b) the set of device drivers built into your guest kernel (c) any guest configuration like kernel command line or files in the guest filesystem must all agree about what method (emulated serial port? graphics? virtio?) is being used to send the output.